# How to find the manifest class of a jar file?

Tags: java, linux, command-line

I have an application bundled in a `jar` file which I need to launch on Linux environment, but I am unable to figure out which class within this `JAR` file is the application's entry point.

I tried to run it on Windows CMD as below:

```
java -jar build21-jdk13.jar
```

It raised the following error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in build21-jdk13.jar
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The _MANIFEST.MF_ file should be in the _META-INF_ directory of the jar file .

Comment: and a JAR file is just a zip file, so can be viewed or decompressed with standard archive tools (in some cases you may need to rename it to change the file extension to .zip)

Comment: I did decompress the file, also checked the **MANIFEST.MF** and it is exist.

Comment: Here is a link to the official documentation for the entry point : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Answer (score 1):

For a jar to be able to run with `java -jar` command, the `YourJar.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file should be like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: the.package.ClassWithMainMethod
```

In your case, the `Main-Class` property is missing.
An alternative is to run the jar passing the main class as argument:

```
java -jar build21-jdk13.jar the.package.ClassWithMainMethod
```

Comment: I checked the file content, and it miss the *Class-Path* and *Main-Class* ,
is there a way to know which class is? 
Noting that it is an open source code.

Comment: Search for the class with the `main` method.